# "Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property"

Tags: html, typescript, angular

Can't tell what I'm doing wrong here. Tried explicity defining the ngFor directive through CORE_DIRECTIVES, and using let. Is there something I missed?

```
import { Component, Input , Output , EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'panel',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.css'],
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class panelComponent {

  list: String[];
}
```

Getting an error on all ngFors

```
<ul >
  <li *ngFor="let thing of list">
        <p>{{thing}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove

```
 directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
```

use `#` instead of `let` in Angular2 beta that you're obviously using.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess that's what happens when you don't read the change logs :^)