# Angular 2 ngFor course

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular2-directives, ngfor

I am currently doing a course in Udemy and I encountered a problem and I would be happy if you solve it because I am still relatively new in the program and I searched for quite a few answers online.

compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#user of users, #i=index] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@41:12 ("

> ```
> <ul>
>     <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="#user of users, #i=index">
>         ({{i+1}}) {{user.firstName}} <em>{{user.email}}</em>  "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@41:12 Parser Error: Unexpected token
> ```
>
> ## at column 1 in [#user of users, #i=index] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@41:12 ("
>
> ```
> <ul>
>     <li *ngFor="#user of users, #i=index">[ERROR ->]
>         ({{i+1}}) {{user.firstName}} <em>{{user.email}}</em>
>     </li>
> </ul>"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@41:46 Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#user of users, #i=index] in
> ```
>
> ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@41:12 ("
>
>   ({{i+1}}) {{user.firstName}}
>   *[ERROR ->]{{user.email}}*
>
> "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@42:45 Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("
>
> ```
> <ul>
>     <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="#user of users, #i=index">
>         ({{i+1}}) {{user.firstName}} <em>{{user.email}}</em>  "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@41:12
> at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
> at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24312)
> at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:33699)
> at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:33674)
> at eval (compiler.js:33576)
> at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:33576)
> at eval (compiler.js:33446)
> at Object.then (compiler.js:455)
> ```

```
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:33445)
```

[**I see nothing on the site**][1]

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621065/cant-bind-to-ngfor-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property

Comment: that course must be using a much older version of angular.. The ngFor syntax has changed

Answer (score 1):

*remove #users and do there **let users***

```
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index">
        ({{i+1}}) {{user.firstName}} <em>{{user.email}}</em>
    </li>
    </ul>
```